# MVC which controller to use on a nested route

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, controller, routes

I have a simple question regarding the MVC pattern.

Imagine this route: `courses/:course_id/lessons/` to fetch all the `lessons`of a `course`.

Which `controller` would be better to use in the order to serve this `request`?
`CoursesController` or `LessonsController` ?

Honestly i can't see "pros and cons".

Of course someone with much more experience then me could explain to me the best way  to use in the order to resolve this kind of requests.

Comment: Entirely up to you and how you want to organize your server-side code.  There is no universal right answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I tend to think that *controllers* are more like [*façades*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) hence I don't create many small controllers to work with different resource types. That is, I create a controller per aggregate root for a specific area/domain.

Unless there's a strong reason to go the other way, I suggest you that you define a single controller called `CourseController` or whichever is the *aggregate root* in your course business/domain, and you'll try to handle all learning center graph from a single controller.

Moreover, clearly bottom layers of your controllers will show a good separation of concerns and layering, and I expect specific services and other classes / patterns depending on the chosen software development paradigm.